# Netlogo: How to assign a value to a variable from an existing (string) list

Tags: string, list, netlogo

I have a problem as I am trying to a assign a location to a (franchisee) supermarket. I have a list per supermarket brand, which has cities that are repeated as many times as the amount of outlets that supermarket brand has in the given city.

However, with the code I've been using, I cannot get to assign the exact amount of cities I have in my list, it is randomly changing every time.

```
;to create coop franchisees
  create-Fs 32 [
    set HQ-brand "Coop"
    set fcoop-location-outlet ["Zuidlaren" "Zuidlaren" "Nijmegen"   "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Nijmegen"  "Ba neveld" "Barneveld" "Doetinchem"    "Doetinchem"    "Doetinchem"    "Zutphen"   "Huissen" "Amstelveen" "Amstelveen" "Amstelveen"    "Zwolle"    "Zwolle" "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam"    "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam" "Rotterdam"] 
]
```

once I have the list above, I have tried the following, to assign a city outlet to each franchisee (per brand)

trial 1

```
ask Fs with [(HQ-brand = "Coop") and (location-outlet = 0)] [ set location-outlet one-of fcoop-location-outlet ]
```

trial 2

```
ask Fs with [(HQ-brand = "Coop") and (location-outlet = 0)] [ foreach fcoop-location-outlet [set location-outlet one-of fcoop-location-outlet] ]
```

trial 3

```
ask Fs with [(HQ-brand = "Coop") and (location-outlet = 0)] [ set location-outlet n-of 32 fcoop-location-outlet ]
```

I thought that with one-of I would assign one item of the Coop location list to each one of my 32 Coop outlets, but it is random. With the n-of it didn't work and I thought that maybe foreach would work, but it is the same as with the one-of the way I am coding it.

How can I code this so that every time I will have all the items of the list with the cities assigned to one of my Coop outlets? There must be a simple way to do this, but I have been googling it and can't figure it out.

(I am doing this for 8 other supermarkets).

Comment: I am unclear what you are trying to do. Do you have 32 locations and 32 outlets and you are trying to allocate pairs? Your outlet possibilities are in a list, are your location possibilities also in a list?

Comment: yeah, in this case, I have 32 locations that I need to assign to 32 outlets. The outlets are my agents (Fs) and I want to make sure that all of the 32 locations that I have are all assigned to one outlet.
My outlets are agents, so they are not in a list. My locations are in a list (fcoop-location-outlet) and from that list I want to select one location to add to the variable (of my outlets) called location-outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way! A friend helped me with this

so, first the list that has all the locations of the outlets:

```
fcoop-location-outlet
```

has to be made a global instead of a variable of each outlet.

Then, the code should look like this:

```
ask Fs with [(HQ-brand = "Coop") and (location-outlet = 0)] [
 set location-outlet item 0 fcoop-location-outlet 
 set fcoop-location-outlet remove-item 0 fcoop-location-outlet 
]
```

In that way, the item (location) that is added to the location-outlet variable, is deleted from the main list, so it does not get repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough of your code for me to write something that will actually work. I didn't want to get into modifying the list, so create an iterator. Something like this should work. It takes advantage of the fact that `ask` is in random order so you don't need to randomise the list order. I started from -1 so I could increment before assigning (so it doesn't go off the end of the list on the last turtle).

```
to assign-locations
  let iterator -1
  ask turtles
  [ set iterator iterator + 1
    set my-location item iterator fcoop-location-outlet
  ]
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I had just found another way, that I had just posted as well.
I think knowing that it is also possible to do it as you say will help me for some next parts I have to code.